# PHP_Serial.class cannot send chr(242) and chr(243) to COM port

Tags: php, serial-port

I am running PHP 7.3.29 on IIS 10. I am attempting to use [php_serial.class](https://gist.github.com/gravataLonga/6c89821b845d15e939a0) to communicate with a scale device that uses Hex(f2) AKA chr(242) for a start byte and Hex(f3) aka chr(243) for a stop byte.  I can see the characters correctly displayed in my web browser when I echo them, but chr(242) transmits as "r" and chr(243) transmits as "s" or hex(72) and hex(73) respectively.  I have a suspicion that it has something to do with sending as 8bit and being > 128, but I have beat my head against the wall trying to change the charset and the encoding and I am completely stumped.  I have also tried pasting the ò and ó directly in my code as part of the string.  I have also tried hex2bin(F2).  It doesn't really matter what I do, the send output doesn't appear to change even though the browser displays it correctly.

Sample Code:

```
   <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252');
    include "php_serial.class.php"; //Include serial class
    
//SETUP PORT
    $serial = new phpSerial; //New serial port class
    $serial->deviceSet("COM1"); //Set the comport (/dev/ttyS0)
    $serial->confBaudRate(9600); //Set the baud rate
    $serial->confParity("none"); //Set the Parity
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);//Set the word length
    $serial->confStopBits(1); //Set Stop Bit
    $serial->confFlowControl("none"); //Set FLow Control
//DEFINE DATA
    $transmit=chr(242)." ".chr(243);
//OPEN PORT
    $serial->deviceOpen();
//SEND DATA
    $serial->sendMessage($transmit);
//RESULT
    $FeedBack = sprintf($transmit);
    echo $FeedBack;
    ?>
```

Web browser output:
ò ó

Communications monitor:
(Ansi)Text:r s
Hex:72 20 73

Comment: `chr(242)` will produce the _byte value_ of `0xF2`, and encoding does not factor in at any point until you attempt to _display_ the value somewhere, or otherwise do something that tries to infer an encoding. Assuming that `sendMessage()` simply writes the string to the wire as-is, the "communications monitor" and/or the terminal it writes to might be attempting to _display_ the values according to some configured encoding that is not something you expect. If the raw bytes read off the wire are actually `0x72 0x20 0x73` then there's probably something wonky in that `sendMessage()` method.

Comment: Also worth noting that `0xF2` -> `0x72` is the result of flipping the highest bit from `1` to `0`. Feels significant.

Comment: Best I can do is suppose that you might have mismatched serial settings between this script and what the device is expecting.